# Buscar en dos campos de una misma tabla a la vez e insensible a acentos en InnoDB

Tags: sql, innodb, acentos

Hola amigas y amigos verán tengo un código que me debería permitir buscar en dos campos de la misma tabla pero no lo hace.

Lo detallaré mas:

Una tabla llamada "clientes" que tiene un campo llamado "nombre" y

otro campo llamado "apellidos".

En el campo "nombre" hay un valor "Pedro"

En el campo "apellidos": "Hernández Castillo"

Pero cuando hago la búsqueda solo me muestra el resultado si pongo solo "Pedro" o si pongo solo "Hernández Castillo".

Pero si pongo "Pedro Hernández Castillo", entonces NO me muestra nada.

Miren este es mi código que estoy usando:

```
    FROM clientes 
    WHERE 
    CONCAT_WS(' ', nombre, apellidos) LIKE '%$dato_sin_prefijo%' OR
    CONCAT_WS(' ', apellidos, nombre) LIKE '%$dato_sin_prefijo%'
```

---

El segundo problema que tengo es que necesito que la búsqueda no me distinga entre vocales acentuadas y las no acentuadas algo que tampoco consigo que me funcione,
este es el código que estoy utilizando:

```
SELECT * FROM clientes COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

---

El motor de la base de datos es: InnoDB

Si alguien me pudiera ayudar le estaría muy agradecido.

Un saludo a todos.

Comment: Respecto al primer problema, has puesto una condición OR. Esto significa que cuando la primera condición es válida ya no valida la segunda. Probablemente lo que necesites sea un AND, de modo que, cuando busque a "Pedro Hernández Castillo" valide ambos campos, nombre y apellido. Respecto al segundo error, según el manual de MySQL https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html
prueba el comando ```lower_case_table_names```

Comment: Pon en las etiquetas _qué base de datos_ estás utilizando. "El motor de la base de datos es: InnoDB" ¿en MySQL? ¿en MariaDB? Además, elimina la etiqueta "acentos", ya que es genérica. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.